# how to pass a pointer to a function and create a matrix there with the pointer as the starting address?

Tags: c, pointers

Same matrix should be printed but here outside the function its not printing any value of the matrix. What is the issue here?(I dont want the argument name in function and name of variable passed to be same.)

0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
2.000000 2.000000 2.000000 2.000000 2.000000
3.000000 3.000000 3.000000 3.000000 3.000000

0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void tryn(double *a)
{
    int i,j;
    a=(double *)calloc(20,sizeof(double));
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            *(a+i*5+j)=i;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%lf ",*(a+i*5+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


}
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    double *arr;
    tryn(arr);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%lf ",(arr+i*5+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

[the output its giving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsZrt.png)

Comment: `a = malloc(...)` is not going to work. Remember that in C all arguments are pass *by value*, which means the original value in the call  is *copied* into the functions argument variable. By doing the assignment to `a` you only modify the local variable `a`, not the original variable `arr` in the `main` function. Please research *emulating pass by reference in C* for one way to solve your problem. Or, you know, just *return* the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters to functions in C are pass by value.  That means that changes to `a` in `tryn` are not reflected in the calling function, so `arr` in `main` remains uninitialized.

You need to pass the address of `arr` to your function:

```
tryn(&arr);
```

And change the parameter type in the function accordingly:

```
void tryn(double **arr)
{
    double *a=calloc(20,sizeof(double));
    ...
    *arr = a;
}
```